# <AWS VPC> Unable to ping private subnet instance from a public subnet instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc

May I seek for assistance about a lab exercise on AWS VPC that I was going through? Thanks.

I created a new VPC, a public and private subnet respectively, and then launched 2 EC2 instances into each of the subnet respectively. I also setup the security groups required for pinging (ICMP) access on the private subnet security group. However, I could not ping the instance in the private subnet from the instance in the public subnet.

Below are the setup:

VPC: (CIDR block 10.0.0.0/16)

[image]

Public subnet: (CIDR block 10.0.1.0/24)

[image]

Private subnet: (CIDR block 10.0.2.0/24)

[image]

Route table for public subnet:

[image]

Route table for private subnet:

[image]

Security group for public facing instance:

[image]

Security group for private facing instance: (All ICMP - IPv4 allowed from private subnet CIDR block)

[image]

Public facing EC2 instance launched in public subnet:

[image]

Private facing EC2 instance launched in private subnet:

[image]

SSH-ed into public instance, but then cannot ping private instance from there:

[image]

Additionally, tried to SSH into the private instance from the public instance (private key already added to public instance), also failed:

[image]

Thank you very for your help in advance.

Comment: Instead of using CIDR in SG of the private instance, what happens if you use SG of the first instance as a source?

Comment: @Marcin Did a quick test, got the same result.

Comment: You haven't setup by any chance firewall on the instance in UserData that could be blocking the connections from the inside?

Comment: @Marcin no, instances are launched as they are

Comment: And network ACLs are default?

Comment: Yes, as they are, allowing all traffics from all ports inbound and outbound from anywhere

Comment: I just wonder if this might be something to do with your ipv6? The SG for the second instance are only ipv4. Maybe when you ping or ssh, ubuntu is trying to use ipv6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the problem, the security group for the public facing instance is missing an outbound rule.
When this is added back, the ping is successful.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add an Entry rule (in the private instance) with the protocole ICMP (used by ping command) and also had to add an exit rule (in the public instance) with protocole ICMP